# Redux observable retry on timeout

Tags: redux, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I'd like to handle ajax timeouts using redux-observable so that if a timeout occurs (after say 10 seconds) it will retry the request another two times (firing a `SAVE_RETRYING` action every time so the UI can notify the user that it's retrying).

For any other type of error or if we've already retried twice it should just fail and fire a `SAVE_FAILURE` action.

I can make it work if I trigger the `SAVE_RETRYING` action using `store.dispatch` but getting deprecation warnings about this and I'm a bit stuck figuring out how to do it the proper way (adding `SAVE_RETRYING` to the stream that is returned by the epic).

Here's what I have (simplified):

```
function saveEpic(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType('SAVE_CLICKED')
    .mergeMap(action => (
      ajax({
        url: '/a-long-request',
      })
        .timeout(10000)
        .map(() => ({ type: 'SAVE_SUCCESS' }))
        .retryWhen(errors => (
          errors.scan((count, e) => {
            if (count >= 2 || e.name !== 'TimeoutError') {
              throw e;
            } else {
              store.dispatch({ type: 'SAVE_RETRYING', count });
              return count + 1;
            }
          }, 0)))
        .startWith({ type: 'SAVE_STARTED' })
        .catch(() =>
          Observable.of({ type: 'SAVE_FAILURE' }))
    ));
}
```

How can I get that `SAVE_RETRYING` action up to the main stream? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not ideal, but you could use `catch` and undocumented second argument (which is the source observable) to resubscribe. The downside I don't like is you have to count retries in the `mergeMap` callback closure.

```
function saveEpic(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType('SAVE_CLICKED')
    .mergeMap(action => {
      let retries = 0;
      return ajax({
        url: '/a-long-request',
      })
        .timeout(10000)
        .map(() => ({ type: 'SAVE_SUCCESS' }))
        .catch((error, source) => {
          retries += 1;
          if (retries >= 2 || error.name !== 'TimeoutError') {
            return Observable.of({ type: 'SAVE_FAILURE' });
          }

          return source.startWith({ type: 'SAVE_RETRYING', count: retries });
        })
        .startWith({ type: 'SAVE_STARTED' });
    });
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm :) I'll accept as the answer if no one else can provide an answer without the downside in the next little while.